What’s the connection between Psalm 91 & Jesus?
Psalm 91 Seems to be speaking of Christ, especially when the connection is made in Matthew 4 when Satan quotes this psalm To Jesus in order to tempt him. As I understand it, when you invoke part of a psalm you invoke the whole psalm.
Is this psalm exclusively referring to Christ? What are the correlations between what is said in the psalm and the life of Jesus? Are these also promises for the believer today and if they are how are they reconciled when Christians experience pain, disaster & suffering? Is it applied only with an eternal perspective in view?

Actually, Psalm 91 is NOT messianic at all.  Thus, there is no immediate connection with Jesus.
Psalm 91 is simply a wonderful psalm about anyone who:

... who dwells in the shelter of the Most High will abide in the
shadow of the Almighty.

Such people enjoy the spiritual protection of the LORD/YHWH.
Now, when Satan quoted V11 & 12 to Jesus (Matt 4:6) in order to tempt Him to throw Himself from the temple, it was a selective quote that avoided the important caveat in the previous two verses, especially V9:

For you have made the LORD, my refuge, The Most High, your dwelling
place.

Thus, Satan was tempting Jesus to do the opposite of this and worship Satan and not God.
However, the point remains, Psalm 91 is not messianic and its only connection with Jesus is when Satan deliberately misquoted it to Jesus in order to tempt Him.

+1 but of course Jesus is included in those whose well in the shelter of the Most High... just not exclusively so.

Jews and Christians disagree as to whether this psalm pertains to the Messiah. Some Christians take the OP's viewpoint, holding that since one verse applies to Christ, the entire psalm does as well. Others understand several of the other verses of the psalm as applying to Jesus. Matthew Henry's commentary states:

Many think that to Christ, as Mediator, these promises do primarily
belong (Isa. 49:2), not because to him the devil applied one of these
promises (Mt. 4:6), but because to him they are very applicable, and,
coming through him, they are more sweet and sure to all believers.

However, Jewish interpreters, who traditionally ascribe this psalm to Moses, understand it as a teaching that applies to all of God's people. Rahshi, for example, states:

"He will lodge in His shadow," for the Holy One, blessed be He,
protects him. Moses, our teacher, hereby persuades people to take
shelter in the wings of the Shechinah.

Barnes and other Christian commentators agree that the psalm addresses all believers:

"He that dwelleth" - Everyone that so dwells. The proposition is
universal, and is designed to embrace all who are in this condition.
It is true of one; it is true of all.

Conclusion: The fact that Satan quoted this psalm to tempt Jesus does not necessarily mean that the psalm is messianic. However, many Christians do take it that way.

Psalms 91 is a clear prophecy related to Jesus and once upon a time it would quickly be raised as evidence of the messianic nature.  However, many know shy away from it and try and a very general nature to believers.  Why? the simple reason is that it does to 'fit' the crucifixion account as it implies that God will save not crucify Jesus.
A few examples of Psalms 91 – it is clearly talking about a person not a people or nation.
Psalm 91

1 He who dwells in the shelter of the Most High will rest in the shadow of the Almighty.


2 I will say of the LORD, "He is my refuge and my fortress, my God, in whom I trust."


3 Surely he will save you from the fowler's snare and from the deadly pestilence.


4 He will cover you with his feathers, and under his wings you will find refuge; his faithfulness will be your shield and rampart.


5 You will not fear the terror of night, nor the arrow that flies by day,


7 A thousand may fall at your side, ten thousand at your right hand, but it will not come near you.


8 You will only observe with your eyes and see the punishment of the wicked.


10 then no harm will befall you, no disaster will come near your tent.


11 For he will command his angels concerning you to guard you in all your ways;


12 they will lift you up in their hands, so that you will not strike your foot against a stone.


13 You will tread upon the lion and the cobra; you will trample the great lion and the serpent.


14 "Because he loves me," says the LORD, "I will rescue him; I will protect him, for he acknowledges my name.


15 He will call upon me, and I will answer him; I will be with him in trouble, I will deliver him and honor him.


16 With long life will I satisfy him and show him my salvation."


Matthew 4:6 does make a clear and precise connection without doubt to Psalms 91.  Which reiterates Gods protection of Jesus.


A side point, how can Satan tempt God who created Satan – ( James 1:13 – Let no man say when he is tempted, I am tempted of God: for God cannot be tempted with evil, neither tempteth he any man: )therefore implying Jesus cannot be God.

More details please see: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/85952/33268

Really - (1) In the first verse "He" does not exist in the Hebrew. (2) in V2 are you interpreting Messiah (Jesus) as the YHWH and all subsequently?  This would be a wonderful conclusion but not for your theology.

@Dottard (1) could get picky about much of translations in the bible and making assumptions like ‘selective quote’.  Even than the text as a whole should be looked at and would indicate a particular person.   (2) not sure I understand – but 1 God  Matt 4:10 ….‘You shall worship the LORD your God, and Him only you shall serve.’ ”.

If this psalm is about Jesus, then why was He crucified and not recued?

@Dottard - Thats the point he was not crucified - no evidence – Remember they all fled Matt 26:56 - so how  could they write about something when they were not even there?  It would also cause a lot of contradictions in the OT such as Psalms 20, 21, 34, 41, 116, even if you do not accept 91 as being related to Jesus.      Apocalypse of Peter  & Gospel of Thomas confirms no crucifixion.

For more see - Jesus was not ‘forsaken’ https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/62632/33268
I must add to this when I get the time as there is so much more.

Amazing!!  So you do not believe 1 Cor 15:3-8?

@Dottard – No one has ever been able to provide me with any evidence in the OT scriptures that Jesus was crucified and raised after 3 days, please let me know if you find some!  The only thing you will find is Paul making his own stories  - “Remember that Jesus Christ of the seed of David was raised from the dead according to my gospel:” 2 Timothy 2:8

You are welcome to your non-Christian belief because the death and resurrection of Jesus is the cornerstone of the Christian faith.  I have personally compiled a large amount of evidence that Jesus both died and was resurrected.  But that is just little old me who believes what the Bible says.

@Dottard please share one OT evidence

Jesus was crucified and resurrected in the NT!!  Ask a specific question and I will answer it.

I’m pleased we agree on something that there is no evidence of Jesus crucifixion foretold in the OT.  So what scriptures was 1 Cor 15:3-8 referencing ?    Happy to go to discussion for you to show me your evidence

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@Dottard that was a bit of a waste of time, whenever you have your so called evidence ready please let me know!

I have posted an answer here >> https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/1431/what-scriptures-is-paul-referring-to-in-1-cor-154/96790#96790
